In angular is there any way are we using closure concept?
I was going through the resources and found that accessing values from classes using getter methods is a form of closure. Since the resources are AI-generated, I'm verifying whether this is indeed a form of closure or if we can use the concept of closure in Angular in any way.

To ask if it is possible to use the concept of closures in any way in angular is equal to the question if it's possible to use the concept of a house in any way when located in the jungle. The only honest answer to such a question is "of course" 
For a more concrete answer, it'd help if you could narrow down what your concrete ideas were for using closures.
Additionally:
I think it's not correct to state that "[...] accessing values from classes using getter methods is a form of closure". You can think of a closure as being a value inside another context which is "closed over" the value. That said, it's usually not possible to reach the value from outside the context.
The following implementation for example is not based on closures, although perfectly valid by the "rules" your sentence implies:
class Counter {
  get number() {
    const c = this.__count ? this.__count + 1 : 1;
    this.__count = c;
    return c;
  }
}

Even though it provides a getter method, the following is still possible:
const count = new Counter();
count.__count = 5;           // <-- note the __
console.log(count.number);   // <-- logs "6"

Contrast it with a classic example of a closure:
function makeCounter() {
  let value = 0;       // <-- "value" is the closure
  return function () {
    value += 1;
    return value;
  }
}

Sure, you can "read" the value of the closure by calling the returned function:
const count = makeCounter();
console.log(count());        // <-- logs "1"
console.log(count());        // <-- logs "2"

However, you cannot "set" the value to anything, because you are not allowed to access it's binding.
Since the addition of private properties in classes, you can "emulate" the way closures work with them:
class Counter {
  #count = 0;
  get number() {
    const c = this.#count + 1;
    this.#count = c;
    return c;
  }
}

And then:
const counter = new Counter();
console.log(counter.number); // <-- logs "1"
console.log(counter.number); // <-- logs "2"

But even though it feels like working with closures to some extend, I still would not say it is a closure - it's a private property.
